# Is this an undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, undefined-behavior

So I just wanted to ask is this an undefined behavior when the commented line is added. Although there is no compilation errors and both of them give the same answers. I would like to know is there any difference. Is the address being overwritten by the address of a. Also If one were to do this (i.e allocate memory for b), would `memcpy()` be a good solution. This may be a trivial example but I would like to understand the difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *a;
    int *b;
    a=malloc(sizeof(int));
    //b=malloc(sizeof(int));
    int c=6;
    a=&c;
    b=a;
    printf("%d\n",*b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a memory leak.

Comment: Note that `a=malloc(sizeof(int)); a=&c;` is also creating memory leak.

Comment: With or without the comment, your program behaves badly. Well-defined, but badly. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you uncomment `//b=malloc(sizeof(int));` part, you'll end up creating [memory leak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), as later, you'll be losing the pointer returned by `malloc()` and will have no way to `free()` it.

*FWIW, you already have the issue with `a`, as you overwrite `malloc()`ed memory by the address of `c`*.

It is **not UB**, though, a bad practice, anyway.

For the above code, you can remove both the `malloc()`s, safely. You don't need them.

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)`, at least, to conform to the standards.

Comment: Is overwriting a malloced memory bad in general. In case the need arises such as if I want to assign 1 pointer (pointer to structures) to the other does both of them need to be mallocd or allocating memory for one pointer is enough ? @Sourav Ghosh

Comment: @ArunSrikanthSridhar Yes, it is a bad idea. Wait, before that, it is a sign of misconception. If you don't need the malloed memory, why to malloc in first place? :) You got the point?

Comment: In general my question is assigning a malloced memory let it be any data type, When you want to assign that memory to another of the same data type would that have to be malloced before assigning?

Answer (score 2):

```
b=malloc(sizeof(int));
int c=6;
a=&c;
b=a;
```

Since the value of `b` is changed before it's used, that you assign the return value of `malloc` to `b` makes no difference. However, you don't `free` it, so you do leak the memory allocated.

No UB.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this code cause undefined behavior, but this code do cause memory leak.

Don't use `malloc()` if you don't need additional buffer.